Is there a way to add proxy to Tauri webview?
I need to add a proxy to the window itself, so that all requests from that window are made through the http or socks5 proxy.
Is this even possible? because I did not find any information on the internet.
Thank you very much for your reply!

This is possible using wry: https://docs.rs/wry/latest/wry/struct.WebViewBuilder.html#method.with_proxy_config, but I couldn't find a way to call this API from tauri.

There's proxy_url parameter inside Window Configuration:
let mut window_builder = WebviewWindowBuilder::new(app, "proxy", tauri::WebviewUrl::External("https://duckduckgo.com".parse().unwrap()));
#[cfg(desktop)]
{
    window_builder = window_builder
    .title("Proxy Example")
    .inner_size(1000., 800.)
    .min_inner_size(600., 400.)
    .content_protected(true)
    .proxy_url("socks5://127.0.0.1:1337".parse().unwrap());
}

let window = window_builder.build().unwrap();
window.show().unwrap();

I did a post about this earlier.

For server I used fast-socks5
